# C++ Cygwin compiled file (.exe file) not being found

Tags: c++, cygwin

I'm using Cygwin to compile and run my c++ files. I have already been able to run my files on this computer (just working yesterday), but today I started my computer and tried doing it again, but now it is not working.

When I compile my file, the .exe file (that was working and saved yesterday in the same folder) shows up for a couple of seconds (while the terminal loads the next line of command) then, the .exe file disappears when the terminal brings up the next line of the command prompt.

I have been searching for a fix but can't seem to find a solution, any ideas on what I can do?
I will wait some time and update the post if anything else happens.

Comment: Could you please post the exact command you use to compile?

Comment: That sounds an awful lot like some overzealous antivirus software thinking "hm... someone is generating executables... why would someone do that without being one of my known compilers?", or your files actually being automatically infected by a resident virus (and then possibly cleaned away by the antivirus); have you checked antivirus logs?

Comment: When you say that it disappears, how have you determined that? There could be file permissions problems. I'd suggest looking at the directory and permissions of its files from within Cygwin and also from Windows explorer. I've run into problems in the past with Cygwin misunderstanding Windows permissions, and those issues can then even be propagated from the point-of-view of Windows applications too if a file is copied from within Cygwin.

Comment: @ForceBru . yes sorry. I type g++ -o pa1 pa1.cpp

Comment: @softwariness I have the folder that I am working in open and visible along with the Cygwin terminal. After I type in the compile command (shown above), The .exe file appears in the folder for a second or two. then when the next prompt loads in the terminal (Nathan@Nathan-PC /cygdrive/c/users/Nathan/Desktop/COP3503 followed by the $), the file dissapears from the folder. However, I had this working fine earlier.

Hope this helps